# Typo in tooltip on network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, spelling, network-profile

On the network profile, the tooltip of *accounts* tab has a typo.

> [image: typo]

(it says "accross" instead of "across")

Comment: +1. Note the same typo when looking at other people's network accounts also.

Comment: With Jeff gone, there's nobody to come with a giant C and bash the one responsible for this horrible bug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

Thanks for ccoreccting us.

Really wanted to [status-ccompleted](/questions/tagged/status-ccompleted) this...

Comment: Ccould you fix the same error in [other user's accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243152/typo-in-tooltip-on-network-profile#comment794751_243152)?

Comment: @Shokhet - not sure about that. Other ccases may well be more ccomplex. Wouldn't want to butccher a fix.